# Gradle add timestamp to build fails (.apk not found)

Tags: android, gradle, timestamp

Heads up, gradle-gurus! :) My config:

```
def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('_yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss')
    return formattedDate
}

...

fileName = fileName.replace("release", 
    "release" + "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + getDate());

...
```

The gradle is fine, only getDate() causes the issue:

> "m104-release-0.2.9_2017-03-17-06-10-14.apk does not exist on disk."

Is there a chance to solve this with a temporary file (or something else)? A "solution" would be just returning `_yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm` (without seconds), but if I start the build at 
06:10:**58** the build will also fail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this method and let me know if it works

```
def getDate() {
    new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
}
```

One more solution is 
You can define in your build.gradle custom functions and variables.

```
def versionMajor = 3

def buildTime() {
    def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'") // you can change it
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    return df.format(new Date())
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       versionName "${versionMajor}-beta-build-${buildTime()}"
    }
}
```

or if you want to add it in you versionNameSuffix

```
beta {
    versionNameSuffix "-beta-build-${buildTime()}"      
}
```